# Windows Phone 10 emulator is not working(object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: windows, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-8-emulator

After upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 OS, Windows phone Emulator is not working. It shows the following exception.

I have ensured Hyper-V is enabled.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check it out whether you have all this
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/ec0fe6fa-d6ee-4c56-af1b-52bd5c0b1b1f/uwperror-the-emulator-is-unable-to-set-some-properties-on-virtual-machine-when-running-windows?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thanks @VictoryJessie after I removed and added the Virtual Switch Manager its working fine.

Comment: Nice to know that your problem was resolved :)